# How to use event on a menu click for a Joomla plugin?

Tags: events, plugins, joomla, menu, triggers

I would like to use a event for a Joomla plugin on a menu selection only on certain menus or categories. How is that done? Is there a current plugin that does that so I can look at the code?

Rick

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this at https://github.com/betweenbrain/hideitems/blob/master/hideitems.php

The basic idea is to do something like:

```
function onAfterRender() {

    // The curent item ID
    $itemId      = JRequest::getInt('Itemid', 0);    
    // Parameter with item ids to run they are the item ID 
    $targetIds   = $this->params->get('targetIds');

    // Check if we are viewing a target ID
    if (strpos($targetIds, $itemId)){

        // do something awesome
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE:

}
```